# Dates and time zones (javascript, java, struts)

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am sure this is a very very common problem.

I have a struts action that uses a common jquery datepicker calendar to select a date for my code to use. Problem is that our production servers live in Texas on CST, but I am in DC on EST. My web browser sends 12/6/11 12:00 AM EST (midnight) and it is interpreted as 12/5/11 11:00 PM CST by the server.

Any recommended ways to fix this?

Should I send the local browser's timezone as a parameter to my web services code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, *always* deal with UTC times internally in your code (and especially in communications between components). Convert to local time at the last possible moment before display, where you *know* what the user's time zone is.

In your case, convert the timestamp to UTC *in the browser* before sending to the server.

If you're doing something like setting appointment times in the future, beware of Daylight Saving Time, where everything gets shifted by an hour twice a year (but UTC doesn't). For example, the user will expect that setting an appointment for "next Tuesday at 2:00 pm" will work even if next Tuesday is a different UTC offset from now.